# What is the best way to manage "non-SQL Server" SQL objects within Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, version-control, database-project, sap-ase

Visual Studio has a Database Project for Sql Server. This has a number of advantages: it hosts configuration settings, and database objects in one place. The .sql files are part of the regular .NET solutions - visible in the Solution Explorer and editable in Visual Studio. And they have a mechanism for generating a deployment script. With each individual database object in it's own file, the tracking of changes and source control is greatly simplified.

Has anyone had any success with using Database Projects with "non-SQL Server" databases? We use Sybase - which uses T-SQL and is very similar to SQL Server so I'm hopeful.

Or is there an alternative approach? I guess I could use a standard project (.csproj) and call a custom commandline application as part of the post-build to convert the .sql files into a deployment script.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: If you create N stored Sybase stored procs, those can be version controlled, right? TFS doesn't care about what the target database is-it's a text file ergo it can be under source control. Asking for clarification as the title doesn't quite sync with the body (can VSTS DB projects work with Sybase)

Comment: @billinkc - Yeah, the easy part is creating the N .sql files and getting them into source control. It's just they would be very hard to work with like that. I'd like them to be part of my regular .NET solution in Visual Studio. Just wondering if there is a better way. Database Projects look great, but seem to be geared purely towards Microsoft Sql Server. Somebody must be using other databases with Visual Studio and TFS. The title was originally "What's the best way..." but the question editor said it was too subjective :-(

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with TFS, I would rewrite the question to focus on how to shape the VS-solution to contain Sybase objects. If you achieve it, just check it in!

Comment: Ok, I've rewritten the question following your feedback @pantelif. Sorry if that makes your comments look a bit out of place. I guess source control is an important aspect of this for me, but the fact that I use TFS is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you looking to create a database project from a Sybase db that's already built and reverse engineering the schema into files, or have the files already been created? I'm not sure if it will reverse engineer for non SQL Server, but maybe there's a template out there like there is for Oracle. As for adding the files to your solution, you should be able to add them using the SQL Server folder structure, changing it where you need it. If you were just looking for source control you can always  use the TFS plugin for Windows Explorer.

Comment: I did find this Template for VS2010: http://sqlinstaller.codeplex.com/. It doesn't list Sybase unfortunately, but it might get you on the right track. It says  "SQL Installer.NET is a toolset which assists in the development, deployment, and maintenance of applications which interface with a relational database management system (RDBMS). It supports a wide range of RDBMS products including: Microsoft SQL Server * Oracle * IBM DB2 * PostGreSQL * Firebird SQL * MySQL * SQLite * Teradata".

Comment: @StoneFX - Great link. I watched the video. The tool looks good, but not quite what I wanted. I guess I can use any old VS project and add the .sql files to it. That'll get it under source control. The great thing about database projects is that you can deploy them to a script file - which takes all of the separate .sql files and combines them into something that I can hand off to someone else to run. I've been messing around writing a simple C# console application that runs post-build and assembles a deployment script for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll answer my own question.

I added all of our SQL objects to their own .sql files within a Visual Studio .dbproj project. However, minor syntactic incompatibilities between the [Sybase version of RAISERROR](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.commands/html/commands/commands74.htm) and the [Microsoft version of RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) caused the validation code built into Visual Studio to get unhappy. The problem with the database project was that this actually caused a compilation error - which basically made it into a show-stopper.

So I scrapped that idea and added the .sql files to a standard .csproj project file. I then implemented some custom code that would load all of the .sql files, and aggregate them into a deployment script when invoked. I added a call to the custom code to the post build of the .csproj file so that whenever it was compiled - it would output a deployment script - which works like a dream with our build server.

In order to get some of the benefits of the .dbproj, I looked into writing a full SQL parser, but was quickly discouraged by some of the posts on SO. Instead I did some rudimmentary parsing with regex - which got me a few cool features without a lot of effort:

1. The code could detect dependencies between the various .sql files, and add them to the deployment script in the correct order to avoid sysdepends warnings.
2. Where there were no dependencies, objects were ordered based on the object type (stored procedure, function, grant statement, etc) and then by name so that the resulting script was always ordered the same - which is very important if you need to diff two versions of the script.
3. The deployment script can figure out some of the required permissions, so I don't need to keep track of all of the GRANT statements.
4. Stored procedures that are in the database but not in the script can be dropped automatically - so I don't need to keep track of what state each database is in - we just run the script and everything is in the correct state.
5. We have a few stored procedures that our automated tests call that shouldn't be deployed. The code can detect these and include them in a Debug build and exclude them in a Release build.
6. The custom code also generates a diff script that determines what changes the deployment script will make to a database and prints them out. This allows the person who is running the script to get an idea of what it will do. For example, the diff script might tell them that no changes will be made - so they don't need to run the deployment script at all - which is kind of handy if it saves them logging in at 3am to take a database offline and take backups etc.

So the end result is that all of my SQL objects are in separate files making them easy to work with in Visual Studio and manage under source control. For the first time since I started this job, I can look at the history in source control and tell what files have been changed (before this we had one enormous .sql file with absolutely everything in it).

Comment: I came across exactly the same issue and I wonder if you could share your code for the solution and how to use it. Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderGaisman - Unfortunately the code belongs to my employer so I can't share it. The basic idea above (console app to generate .sql deployment script from separate .sql files for each object) works well and doesn't require much coding. The hardest bit is probably dependency tracking. We've taken this much further since I posted this so the generated script also includes the ability to: deploy stored proc without downtime (getting rid of 6 above); detect changes and only apply the delta (getting rid of 4); apply different stored proc versions depending on detected schema etc.